# Can't install bitcoind in upgraded system due package conflicts

Tags: 12.04, apt, bitcoin

I was previously using Ubuntu 10.04 and I tried to install `bitcoind`. This failed and I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04. When I run `bitcoind` it still doesn't work:

```
$ bitcoind    
************************
EXCEPTION: 11DbException       
Db::open: Invalid argument       
bitcoin in AppInit()       

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'DbException'
  what():  Db::open: Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Also, trying to re-install does not work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bitcoind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bitcoind
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 981 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,873 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu/ precise/main bitcoind amd64 0.8.5-precise1 [981 kB]
Fetched 981 kB in 7s (130 kB/s)                                                                                               
(Reading database ... 222704 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bitcoind (from .../bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bitcoind', which is also in package bitcoin 0.3.24-ppa2~lucid
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I get `bitcoind` working? I don't mind un-installing and re-installing if that is what it takes.

**update 1**

I just tried removing the package and installing again, but still no luck:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge bitcoind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bitcoind is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install bitcoind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bitcoind
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 981 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,873 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu/ precise/main bitcoind amd64 0.8.5-precise1 [981 kB]
Fetched 981 kB in 7s (136 kB/s)                                                                                               
(Reading database ... 222704 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bitcoind (from .../bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bitcoind', which is also in package bitcoin 0.3.24-ppa2~lucid
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: i'm running ubuntu 12.04 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end this was the solution:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This could cause problems later, why didn't you did the other methods?

Comment: none of them worked. but this one did.

Comment: You still have 2 binaries for bitcoin, if you don't delete them both you will surely get problems. If you have weird behaviors later remember to give a link to this one.

Comment: cheers for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, and see if it installs. First install pre-requisites needed to run bitcoind.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get purge bitcoind
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoind
```

and then everything is OK.

Comment: This is incomplete in the instructions of commands, I have done a revision as such.

Answer (score 1):

The `bitcoin` package is still there! Installed!

The complete set of commands is:

```
sudo apt-get purge bitcoin*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoind
```

The problem is that you still have a package called `bitcoin` which hasn't been uninstalled. Once you do this, your installation should be fine.

This should be reported as bug to the packages managers